# Обращение и изменение текста class через body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть body с классом product-product-41
Внутри него есть элемент с классом control-label.

Вопрос. Как правильно обратиться к control-label, через body, который тоже имеет класс, и в control-label изменить текст на другой? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
<body class="product-product-41">
    <div>
        <label class="control-label">Количество:</label>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.product-product-41 .control-label').innerHTML='Количество: '`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```
let label = document.querySelector('.product-product-41 .control-label'); // Обратимся к элементу
label.classList.remove('control-label'); // Удалим класс
label.classList.add('you-class'); // Добавим новый класс
```

jQuery

```
//                                                   классы разделяются пробелом
//                                                               \/
$('..poduct-product-41 .control-label').toggleClass('control-label you-class');

// Аналог записи как на JS
$('.poduct-product-41 .control-label').removeClass('control-label').addClass('you-class');
```